# Defining a new example environment and giving reference it

Tags: hyperref, environments, ref, examples

How to give cross-reference to all words, **Example 1**, as follows?

[image]

I defined a new environment as follows:

`\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}`

When I give a `\label{Example}` to the example and write `\ref{Example}`, I get:
[image]

just **1** includes the link.

```
`\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
 
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue}
\usepackage[all]{xy,xypic}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,amsgen,amsopn,amsbsy,theorem,graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage{multicol}  
\usepackage{eufrak,amscd,bezier,latexsym,mathrsfs,enumerate,multirow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\DontPrintSemicolon
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}
     \newtheorem{rem}{Remark}
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\let\example\relax
\let\endexample\relax
%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{exmp} \label{Ex1}
 Let's consider:
 \begin{equation}
     2x+y=3
 \end{equation}
 \end{exmp}

\begin{table*}[h!]
    \caption{Results in \cref{EX1}

.....
\end{document}`
```

Comment: You should take a look at the `cleveref` package (to be  loaded *after* `hyperref`)..

Comment: In fact, I usually `cleveref` and  `\cref`. But it doesn't work in here.

Comment: Could you post a minimal, yet complete, code that we can text to see what happens?

Comment: Thank you. I edited the OP.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't compile your code. I don't have some packages installed (unrelated to the problem such as subfig, which is obsolete), vut more important there seems to be conflicts between packages. Could you post a code with only the relevant packages?

Comment: I think there is a conflict between the packages. I am not capable to find the conflict.  I get the following errors: `LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{example}.} ` and `LaTeX Error: Environment example undefined.` May be `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty, line 66 LaTeX Error: Command \theoremstyle already defined.`

Comment: I did some editings: Now, I get  the errors:   `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty, line 66 LaTeX Error: Command \theoremstyle already defined.`  and `Reference  EX1 on page 1 undefined on input line 572.`. But When I use `\cref{EX1}`, I get ?? in the location.

Comment: I noticed that I also defined `Remark` environment. `\cref` works for it. I don't understand where is the problem for `Example` environment

Comment: I used `\newtheorem{example}{Example}` instead of `\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}`. It's been solved.